# Sequential boxes with 3 Random Box Shadow Colors

Tags: jquery

**Case:**

I use Owl Carousel for the boxes with maximum 10 thumbnails (that will scroll manually across the browser with define width each panel). However, I've searched Google on "how create 3 random colors using jQuery" and seems some of the results are difficult for me to integrate.

**Code Fig.1**

```
BoxShadow = function() {
  var hfiColors = ['#00A9E0', '#E82425', '#EFB12A'];
  var colors = hfiColors.slice(0);

  $('.program-gallery .item').each(function(i){
    var i = i + 1;
    var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);

    $(this).css('box-shadow', '0 0 0 5px' + colors[color]);
    colors = colors.slice(0,color-1).concat( colors.slice(color+1,colors.length-1) );
  });

  $.each(colors, function(i, v){
    $('.item' + (+i + 1)).html(colors[i]);
  });
}
$(document).ready(BoxShadow);
```

This is the code i have so far, and it generates random box-shadow to my thumbnails, but some box-shadows to my thumbnails are not displaying correctly. Honest to tell, I am confuse now on the code structure.

**Code Fig.2**

```
<div class="program-gallery">
  <div class="item">
    <figure class="uk-overlay uk-overlay-hover">
      <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=1600&h=980&txt=0&random=201" alt="">
      <figcaption class="uk-overlay-panel uk-overlay-background uk-overlay-fade uk-flex uk-flex-bottom">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit consequuntur.
      </figcaption>
      <a class="uk-position-cover"></a>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <figure class="uk-overlay uk-overlay-hover">
      <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=1600&h=980&txt=0&random=202" alt="">
      <figcaption class="uk-overlay-panel uk-overlay-background uk-overlay-fade uk-flex uk-flex-bottom">
        Suscipit blanditiis quos aspernatur minus optio beatae consectetur quidem accusantium rerum ab sed nisi.
      </figcaption>
      <a class="uk-position-cover"></a>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <figure class="uk-overlay uk-overlay-hover">
      <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=1600&h=980&txt=0&random=203" alt="">
      <figcaption class="uk-overlay-panel uk-overlay-background uk-overlay-fade uk-flex uk-flex-bottom">
        Culpa consequuntur necessitatibus laboriosam, quas quos odit non unde consequatur fugit rerum incidunt.
      </figcaption>
      <a class="uk-position-cover"></a>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

**What To Achieve:**

I would like to create a 3 random box-shadow colors (only) over to each (10 thumbs) of `.item` class.

**Photo Fig.1**
[image: Sample Owl Carousel Output with Box-Shadow 3 Random Colors]

Comment: Please provide a working example (and not just part of your javascript code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable string containing alphabets from `A` through `F` and numbers `0` through `9`, use `String.prototype.concat()` and `Array.from()` to concatenate random characters from string variable to set `box-shadow` of elements.

```js
$(function() {
  var base = ['#00A9E0', '#E82425', '#EFB12A'];
  var shadow = "0 0 0 5px ";

  function randomColor() {
    return shadow + base[Math.floor(Math.random() * base.length)]
  }
  
  $(".item").each(function() {
    $(this).css("boxShadow", randomColor())
  })
})
```

```css
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
<div class="item">7</div>
<div class="item">8</div>
<div class="item">9</div>
<div class="item">10</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, though my client required these 3 colors only (`['#00A9E0', '#E82425', '#EFB12A']`) for each of the `div.item` panel.

Comment: @iMarkDesigns You can substitute `var base = ['#00A9E0', '#E82425', '#EFB12A'];` and `return shadow + base[Math.floor(Math.random() * base.length)]` for `base` and return value of `randomColor`, respectively, to set a random `box-shadow` for the elements. Are you trying to set the `box-shadow` in same order in succession for each set of three element? Or, use random selection of the three colors?

Answer (score 1):

```js
BoxShadow = function() {
  var hfiColors = ['#00A9E0', '#E82425', '#EFB12A'];
  var colors = hfiColors.slice(0);

  $('.program-gallery .item img').each(function(){
    var colorIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);    
    $(this).css('box-shadow', '0 0 0 5px' + colors.splice(colorIndex, 1));
  });
}
$(document).ready(BoxShadow);
```

```css
.item { width: 30%; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top; }
img { max-width: 100% }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="program-gallery">
  <div class="item">
    <figure class="uk-overlay uk-overlay-hover">
      <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=1600&h=980&txt=0&random=201" alt="">
      <figcaption class="uk-overlay-panel uk-overlay-background uk-overlay-fade uk-flex uk-flex-bottom">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit consequuntur.
      </figcaption>
      <a class="uk-position-cover"></a>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <figure class="uk-overlay uk-overlay-hover">
      <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=1600&h=980&txt=0&random=202" alt="">
      <figcaption class="uk-overlay-panel uk-overlay-background uk-overlay-fade uk-flex uk-flex-bottom">
        Suscipit blanditiis quos aspernatur minus optio beatae consectetur quidem accusantium rerum ab sed nisi.
      </figcaption>
      <a class="uk-position-cover"></a>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <figure class="uk-overlay uk-overlay-hover">
      <img src="https://placem.at/things?w=1600&h=980&txt=0&random=203" alt="">
      <figcaption class="uk-overlay-panel uk-overlay-background uk-overlay-fade uk-flex uk-flex-bottom">
        Culpa consequuntur necessitatibus laboriosam, quas quos odit non unde consequatur fugit rerum incidunt.
      </figcaption>
      <a class="uk-position-cover"></a>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update your codes abit. And added some CSS for visuals.

```
$('.program-gallery .item img').each(function(){ 
// I targeted each image instead of `.item`
```

Instead of having to slice and concat your array to remove an item from it, just use `splice`:

```
$(this).css('box-shadow', '0 0 0 5px' + colors.splice(colorIndex, 1));
```